# Как можно решить проблему с повторяющейся стилизацией?

Tags: c#, wpf

В общем, есть у меня кнопки, которые состоят из картинки и тултипа внутри:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что каждой такой кнопке нужно прописать Style...

Вроде, в TagetType стиля нельзя указать различные условия для применения.

Какие могут быть решения данной проблемы?

Есть мысля-сделать наследование, но если делать по умному, то нужно запрещать в такую кнопку что-либо сувать, а это по моему геморно...

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос. Задайте базовый стиль для всех кнопок тулбара где-нибудь в `.Resources` родительского контейнера `<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ToolbarButtonStyle">...</Style>` и используйте его в локальных стилях для каждой кнопки `<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ToolbarButtonStyle}">...</Style>`. Так работает наследование стилей.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Стили все одинаковые, или все разные?

Comment: В том, что в в рамках окна есть кнопки которым нужно применить один стиль, а к другим другой. И вопрос в том, можно ли сделать так, чтобы конкретной каждой кнопке не прописывать стиль, а сказать "Вот эту группу кнопок оформи так, а другую так"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Ваша библиотека стилей -->
    <Style x:Key="BaseButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="RedButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="GreenButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <!-- Для всех кнопок в этом контейнере по умолчанию
                будет использоваться стиль RedButton -->
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource RedButton}"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <!-- Для всех кнопок в этом контейнере по умолчанию
                будет использоваться стиль GreenButton -->
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource GreenButton}"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image: Результат]